# Find all properties without BrowsableAttribute explicitely set to Yes in .Net

Tags: .net, typedescriptor, browsable

Is there a way to find all the properties of a given type without the [BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) explicitly set to Yes in .Net?

I've tried the following code without success (all the properties which are browsable by default are also returned):

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection browsableProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type, new Attribute[] { BrowsableAttribute.Yes });
```

Comment: This is kind of broad.. What answer are you looking for? Have you looked at PropertyInfo, Reflection, anything? Short answer is probably "yes", is that what you want to know?

Comment: Any answer welcomed :)
I'm updating my question with what I tried if that can help

Comment: Well yeah, defining what expected outcome you want from a given class for instance would help immensely for adding constraints to the problem, and adding information for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of reflection and linq will help here.

```
var result =  type
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(x =>
            x.GetCustomAttribute<BrowsableAttribute>() == null ||
            !x.GetCustomAttribute<BrowsableAttribute>().Browsable)
    .ToList();
```

You can introduce a local variable to avoid calling `GetCustomAttribute` method twice.

If you're in .Net framework version less than 4.5 you can write your own `GetCustomAttribute` extension method like this

```
public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this MemberInfo element) where T: Attribute
{
    return (T) element.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, there are a few errors (it's GetCustomAttributes, not GetCustomAttribute, and it's missing a cast), but I got the idea and it does the job!

Comment: @GyumFox There is also a version of [GetCustomAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have a GetCustomAttribute method though, which is what you are working with

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't see the extension method

Comment: Looks like GetCustomAttribute is only available starting form .NET 4.5

Comment: @SriramSakthivel If you see the edit history you will get that I had improved your answer not vandalized. If you see my last edit I had added `using` in the snippet which is necessary if using Extension method. My edit was necessary so that anyone visiting in future would get the answer as whole without going thru comments where you have provided the final part of the answer to the OP i.e. add the `using System.Reflection` to exactly use provided code.

Comment: @HarshBaid What about first two edits? Wrong edit, then rolled back? Why? using directive is trivial one. and I've not added my code in any method which is invalid in c# so is that a problem?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm using .Net 4.0
Thanks though for improving the answer and making clear what is the supported version.

Comment: @GyumFox I've updated my answer, you can write your own extension method easily :)

Comment: I made initial edit based on very first comment by @GyumFox then I saw your comment that your code is correct and you have used extension method so I rollback and added the `using` block to complete the answer for other for whom adding the extension method is not so obvious (coz they may not have Resharper which has intellisense for extension method). Try once by creating new project and this block then try `ctrl`+`.` it won't show anything and generally we will thing that its bad code, until you manually go and add the minimum required `using` on top of your class.